# Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 - Set wifi channel in Monitor Mode with WDK and NDIS

Tags: c++, wifi, wdk, ndis, netmon

I'm writing a program (C++) which will detect devices around me using Wi-fi on Windows OS.
In order to do that I'm using WDK and NDIS to switch the wireless network adapter to monitor mode in the following way:

```
WlanSetInterface(
. . . ,
wlan_intf_opcode_current_operation_mode,
DOT11_OPERATION_MODE_NETWORK_MONITOR);
```

Does anyone know how to **set a specific channel** to monitor? I would appreciate a code sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this issue?